# State design pattern modifying context class collection - How to unit test.

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, nunit, nsubstitute

I am currently using nSubstitute and nUnit to do some unit testing. I a newbie when it comes to this stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please have a look at this code:

```
public class Event
{
    private ISet<Host> hostSet; 
    private IEventState eventState; 

    public Event()
    {
        hostSet = new HashSet<Host>(); 
        eventState = new StartedEvent(); 
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; protected internal set; }

    public virtual bool CanSetName()
    {
        return eventState.CanSetName(); 
    }

    public virtual void SetName(string name)
    {
        eventState.SetName(this, name);
    }

    internal virtual ISet<Host> HostSet
    {
        get
        {
            return hostSet; 
        }
    }

    public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<Host> HostCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<Host>(hostSet.ToList()); 
        }
    }

    public virtual bool CanAddHost()
    {
        return eventState.CanAddHost(); 
    }

    public virtual void AddHost(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        eventState.AddHost(this, firstName, lastName);
    }

    internal virtual void ChangeState(IEventState eventState)
    {
        this.eventState = eventState; 
    }

}

public class Host
{
    private readonly string firstName; 
    private readonly string lastName;

    public Host(string firstName, string lastname)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName; 
        this.lastName = lastname; 
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName; 
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName; 
        }
    }
}

public interface IEventState
{
    bool CanSetName(); 
    void SetName(Event evnt, string Name); 
    bool CanAddHost(); 
    void AddHost(Event evnt, string firstName, string lastName); 
}

internal class StartedEvent : IEventState
{

    public bool CanSetName()
    {
        return true; 
    }

    public void SetName(Event evnt, string name)
    {
        evnt.Name = name; 
    }

    public bool CanAddHost()
    {
        return true; 
    }

    public void AddHost(Event evnt, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        evnt.HostSet.Add(new Host(firstName, lastname)); 
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class StartedEventState
{
    [Test]
    public void CanSetName_Always_ReturnsTrue() 
    {
        IEventState eventState = new StartedEvent();
        bool result = eventState.CanSetName();
        Assert.True(result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void SetName_WhenCalled_ChangesTheEventName() 
    {
        Event evnt = Substitute.For<Event>();
        IEventState eventState = new StartedEvent();
        eventState.SetName(evnt, "Test Event");
        evnt.Received().Name = "Test Event";
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanAddHost_Always_ReturnsTrue() 
    {
        IEventState eventState = new StartedEvent();

        bool result = eventState.CanAddHost();

        Assert.True(result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void AddHost_WhenCalled_AddsTheHostToTheEvent()
    {
        //No idea how to test this? 
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class EventTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CanSetName_WhenCalled_DelegatesToItsCurrentState()
    {
        Event evnt = new Event();
        var eventState = Substitute.For<IEventState>();
        evnt.ChangeState(eventState);
        evnt.CanSetName();
        evnt.Received().CanSetName();
    }
}
```

The tests that are currently written all pass. However I have no idea how to perform a test to ensure that the StartedEvent.AddHost method is correctly calling the context class and adding it to the set. I have tried a few different things but have failed miserably.

1) Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I go about testing this method. 
2) It would be good if someone could confirm my existing tests are OK.

Comment: I only see one state in the design. Is your code incomplete? Not sure why you're using the state pattern. Do you have a state-transition diagram (or table) that shows how your code is supposed to work? Testing should validate those transitions.

Comment: Yes the code is incomplete there are a whole bunch of other states. I am comfortable testing the transition from one state to another.

Answer (score 1):

To test `StartedEvent.AddHost`:

1. Create an `Event`

   Event event = new Event();
2. Create an `EventState`

   IEventState eventState = new StartedEvent();
3. Call `StartedEvent.AddHost` on it:

   eventstate.AddHost(event, "firstname", "lastname");
4. Inspect `event.HostSet`, checking that it contains only 1 event, and that this event contains the test data you supplied

The only issues that I see with your existing tests are that `SetName_WhenCalled_ChangesTheEventName` and `CanSetName_WhenCalled_DelegatesToItsCurrentState` aren't `Assert`ing anything.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. In regards to my existing tests. I don't need to assert anything in the context class as I am just testing that the context class is calling the state class. The asserting will be done when each individual state is tested? 

I will give it another go i.e. testing the hosts and let you know on the issues I have. cheers.